# 32-bit signed integer math in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am converting some legacy Pascal to JavaScript. I need to multiple two 32-bit signed integers.

In the following sample loop some multiplications will cause overflow and will give negative numbers. This is intentional. I need to reproduce the same final number x at the end that matches the legacy system.

How can I do this in JavaScript to achieve the same result?

Here is some sample code:

```
var x = new Number(some value);  // I need this to be a 32-bit signed integer
var y = new Number(some value); // I need this to be a 32-bit signed integer

for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {   
    x = x * y; 
} 
return x;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Javascript's bitwise operators actually convert the value to a regular integer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators This fact is used by things like asm.js to coerce the types, and you can do it yourself too. The trick is to put a |0 at the end of a number to force it to be 32 bit

```
function test() {
    var x = 255|0; // |0 does the type coercion
    var y = 255|0; // not strictly necessary at this var decl but used for explicitness

    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {   
         x = (y * x)|0; // parens needed because |'s precedence
   } 

   return x;
}
```

I ran that with a few numbers and got the same result as C in Firefox.. didn't get a chance to test in IE, but I'm pretty sure this behavior is in the ECMAscript spec, so it should work.

Comment: I don't think the parnes are required.

Comment: `|` has higher precedence than '*'. But my rule of thumb anyway is if you have to look up or even think more than a second about precedence rules, just write the parens to make is double-clear for the next reader anyway.

Comment: The `|` operator has a very low precedence, `*` has a very high precedence and is most likely to be executed first in operations. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: huh I should have looked it up... you are indeed right. But still, I prefer to write them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Math operations in JavaScript are always done as double-precision floating point.  You'd have to write your own multiplication routine (or find one somewhere) to carry out integer math, and that'd be slow or hard (or both :).

Comment: This is one of the most critically weak aspects of the language, by the way.

Comment: What you say is true but the accepted answer above solves my current problem.

Comment: @Vic well it'll work for some values, but the multiplication operation itself is carried out with floating point hardware as a double-precision operation, so values near the limit of numeric capacity may get weird.

Comment: @Vic actually since there are plenty more mantissa bits than 32, it may work out OK.

Comment: So far my test data has shown the right results. Keeping my figures crossed.

Comment: The trick fails for Java's Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647). In Java: (2147483647 * 2147483647 * 2147483647) = 2147483647; In Javascript: (2147483647 * 2147483647 * 2147483647)|0 = 0;

Comment: There is a simple implementation that does work correctly here: http://jsperf.com/murmurhash3